# LinkedList different implementations

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, queue

I have seen 2 valid declarations of the `LinkedList` class in `Collections Framework` in Java.

1. LinkedList a = new LinkedList();
2. Queue a = new LinkedList();

What exactly is the difference between these 2 implementations?

Answer (score 3):

*Queue* is an interface which *LinkedList* class implements.

In Your first case you **a** is a LinkedList reference to a LinkedList object.
In the latter, **a** is a Queue interface reference pointing to a LinkedList object so, in this last case you will be only able to execute those service of *LinkedList* which are included in *Queue* interface.

Comment: Queue<T> is extendend by Deque<T> and this interface finally implemented by LinkedList<T>

Comment: @Youngistan I don't think that contradicts the fact that, at the end, LinkedList implements Queue services.

Comment: Yes i don't say you answer is incorrect.Just add comment for complete hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

There is just one implementation in your code: LinkedList.

[Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) is one of the multiple interfaces implemented by [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code of LinkedList

```
public class LinkedList<E> extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
  implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, Serializable
```

So as you can see this class implements `Deque<E>` and so on this interface extends `Queue<E>` 
interface so you can create the object as below :

```
Queue B = new LinkedList(); 
Deque d = new LinkedList();
```

In above declaration `LinkedList` object is refer by the `Queue` interface, it mean you can call all the methods declare in `Queue`.